# Windows 7 cannnot recognize Lumia 535 phone drivers

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

I've recently bought a Microsoft Lumia 535. When I connect the phone to the computer (Windows 7) the OS cannot find the correct drivers for the phone.

Windows recognizes that the phone was connected and opens a Windows Phone application but the drivers are still with errors on the device manager. I do need the drivers properly installed so I can connect this phone to the Visual Studio 2013 Dev Tools.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Different USB cables.
- Uninstalling the USB drivers and reconnecting the phone.
- Having the phone connected to the PC while it is rebooting.

Below I've inserted an image with a small "preview" of what is going on:

[image: Problem Preview]

Bottom line is, the Windows OS cannot find a controller for the Lumia 535 (RM-1089).

Comment: You mention VS 2013, but you can't develop for Windows Phone 8.1 on Win7, Win8 or better is required!

Answer (score 3):

Your drivers will get downloaded from the **Windows update** .. so update it when u have an active internet connection or check for updates after u keep your phone connected

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Disconnected the Windows Phone 8 from the Windows 8 PC
2. On the PC, went to Devices and Printers
3. Right-clicked on the Windows Phone icon and chose to "Remove device"
4. Re-connected the phone to the PC

   When it reconnected I had to select what default action to take whenever the phone is connected. I chose to open File Explorer (rather than one of the other scripts, such as import music and videos).

Credits: [Source](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8/202103-why-wont-my-computer-recognize-my-lumia-920-a.html)

Comment: I've tried it with no success. Still no drivers detected.